# Openstack Internal server error in adding external gateway to the router

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I create a router without an `external gateway`. Then, I send the below input to [this](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/network/v2/index.html?expanded=add-external-gateways-to-router-detail#add-external-gateways-to-router) API to add an `external gateway` to the `route`. I get `InternalServerError`. All uuids exist in the `openstack`.

Input:

```
{"external_gateways":[{"enable_snat":true,"external_fixed_ips":[{"ip_address":"37.130.206.150","subnet_id":"b8d2ac22-..."}],"network_id":"419e8adc-2..."}]}
```

Url:

```
 :9696/v2.0/routers/f143df49.../add_external_gateways
```

method_type: PUT

Output:

```
{"NeutronError": {"type": "HTTPInternalServerError", "message": "Request Failed: internal server error while processing your request.", "detail": ""}}
```

Comment: If you're getting an "internal server error" then you'll need to inspect the neutron server logs to determine the nature of the error.